# a/an expected completion date?

Tags: indefinite-articles, phonology, sandhi

Question is pretty self-explanatory. Either way, a date on a calendar is ***a*** date. When it becomes unexpected, it sounds right to me to say ***an*** unexpected date instead of ***a*** unexpected date. Same for when using *expected*.

Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a" is used when the next word begins with a consonant sound

"an" is used when the next word begins with a vowel sound

Therefore it is "an expected completion date" (also I would pronounce the "an" more nasally so it is not confused with unexpected)

Comment: Right, totally makes sense now.

Comment: For some reason I need wait for some minutes before accepting an answer as correct. Will do.